# Why does my jQuery open and close my pop up before clicking the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a pop up that opens up so users can reply to messages. now when a user clicks `<a>` tag it opens the popup, but it doesn't close if they hit anywhere in the body. I tried fixing this by using jquery but it keeps opening and then closing the pop up again immediately after clicking on the  `<a>` tag.

My `<a>` tag:

```html
<a class="msg-icon2"  onclick="openReplyModal(<?php echo $msg_id ; ?>)">
    <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
</a>
```

My jquery:

```
var msg_id;

function openReplyModal(id) {
  msg_id = id
  $("#reply_modal" + msg_id).fadeIn();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery("body").click(function() {

      $("#reply_modal" + msg_id).fadeOut();
    });
  });
}
```

How can I adjust my code so that when the user clicks the button for the first time it would open the popup and stay opened unless he clicks anywhere in the `body`?

here is the code i got from the answer below:

```
`function openReplyModal(id, event) {
  $(".modal").hide(); // close other modal
  msg_id = id
  $("#reply_modal" + msg_id).fadeIn();
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // click on modal doesn't hide itself
  $("body").on("click", ".modal", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

  });
  // clicl anywhere else hides all modals
  $(window).click(function() {
    $(".modal").fadeOut();
    
  });
});`
```

Comment: You shouldn't bind an event handler inside another event handler. Every time you click you're adding another event handler to the modal.

Comment: yeah i realize that but i dont know how to do it in the right way @Barmar can you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all your modals a common class, such as `class="reply_modal"`. Then you can have a general click handler that fades them all out when you click on the body.

The reason that the modal closes immediately is that the `click` event bubbles out from the `<a>` to the body, so it closes the modal. I added `event.stopPropagation()` to the function so it won't bubble out.

Use `$(window).click()` to detect clicks anywhere in the window outside the element. See [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element).

```js
var msg_id;

function openReplyModal(id, event) {
  $(".reply_modal").hide(); // close other modal
  msg_id = id
  $("#reply_modal" + msg_id).fadeIn();
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // click on modal doesn't hide itself
  $("body").on("click", ".reply_modal", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  // clicl anywhere else hides all modals
  $(window).click(function() {
    $(".reply_modal").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.reply_modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="msg-icon2" onclick="openReplyModal(1, event)" href="#"> <i class="fas fa-reply">open 1</i></a>
<a class="msg-icon2" onclick="openReplyModal(2, event)" href="#"> <i class="fas fa-reply">open 2</i></a>
<div id="reply_modal1" class="reply_modal">This is modal 1<br>
  <input></div>
<div id="reply_modal2" class="reply_modal">This is modal 2<br>
  <input></div>
```

Comment: thats the problem, i cant give them all the same id.

Comment: Not the same ID, the same class.

Comment: But if you can't do that, you can use the selector `[id^=reply_modal]` to match all IDs beginning with `reply_modal`

Comment: good answer, but your code still produces the same problem i got. opens then closes immediately

Comment: I was originally having that problem until I added `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: how do i add the event paramater in my <a tag > properly? i did it this way `onclick="openReplyModal('<?php echo $msg_id ; ?>','event')">`

Comment: Don't quote `event`, that makes it a string rather than a variable.

Comment: okay amazing now its opening, but not closing when i click on the body still. i dont understand why, your code seems to be perfectly fine

Comment: Change `$("body")` to `$(window)` to detect a click anywhere in the window, since not eveything is in `body`.

Comment: i played around the code a bit, now it works. really thank you alot for helping. this means alot to JS newbies like me

Comment: but one problem i am facing now is that it closes the pop up when i try to enter my text area.

Comment: Do you have the code after the comment `// click on modal doesn't hide itself`?

Comment: yes, my code is the same as yours now i removed something from the click doesnt hide it self part, but the part thats not working is the //click anywhere else to hide all other modals

Comment: Do you have any other uses of `stopPropagation()`? Those will prevent the click from getting to the body.

Comment: It works for me, so you must have some other code that's interfering.

Comment: ill post it as an answer

Comment: Answers should only be used for solutions, not continuations of the question. Add it as an addition to the question.

Comment: i posted it, my html is detecting the click on the body, but never executing the function `$(".modal").fadeOut(); `why is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            function openReplyModal(id) {
                msg_id = id
                $("#reply_modal" + msg_id).addClass('model-open').fadeIn();
            }

            $('body').click(function (e) {
                $('.model-open').removeClass('open').fadeOut();
            });
        });
```

Comment: this seems really good, but now its not opening my pop up at all. is there anything i should change in my <a > tag?

Comment: it is giving me this error now:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: openReplyModal is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick `

Comment: Functions called from HTML `onclick` have to be defined in the global scope, not inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: so what can i do to adjust this? @Barmar

Comment: @techie_28 as barmar said the function should be global not inside $(document).ready().

Comment: then you do not need the `.ready()` method at all.. move it out & place it in a `script` tag right after the `head` tag